# Git auto-merge binary files

Tags: git, binary

At the below scenario:

- E does a git pull; F does a git pull;
- E edits line 31 of word1.docx;
- F edits line 32 of word2.docx;
- E does a commit and push;
- F does a commit and push; F's push fails.
- F does a pull; Git cannot auto-merge the conflict.

The scenario is about two people made changes to the same copy pulled from central repository, they changed different binary files, will git be able to auto-merge the changes? I understand that if the changes are made in same binary files Git cannot, what about the changes on different binary files.

Comment: There is nothing to merge when different files are being edited. There are no failure points in this case

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen is correct, there is no conflict here in Git's view, because the changes were made to *different files*. Were the changes made to files Git decides are "the same", there *would* be a conflict, and Git would be quite unable to resolve it on its own (`docx` files are structured such that you could potentially write *your own* merge driver, but none such is included in Git).

Comment: Git is not the right tool to try and manage your binary document files (.docx, .pptx, .xlsx, etc.), should be using a content management system or SOL document indexing or something similar.  You're trying to force git out of its sweet spot, IMO.